# How to pack and unpack a long variable given a particular format?

Tags: java, byte, bit-shift

I am packing my `address` variable which is long datatype and it is made up of `datacenter`, `client_id`, `data_id` and `data_counter` as shown below -

```
long address = client_data((byte) 2, (short) 100, (byte) 22, (int) 120);

private static long client_data(byte datacenter, short client_id, byte data_id, int data_counter) {
    return ((long) (datacenter) << 56) | ((long) client_id << 40) | ((long) data_id << 32) | ((long) data_counter);
}
```

Now I want to extract `datacenter`, `client_id`, `data_id` and `data_counter` back from `address` variable? So I started with the below code -

To extract datacenter this is what I am using -

```
value = ((address >>> 56) & ((1 << 8) - 1));
```

To extract client_id this is what I am using -

```
value = ((address >>> 40) & ((1 << 16) - 1));
```

To extract data_id this is what I am using -

```
value = ((address >>> 32) & ((1 << 8) - 1));
```

But how do I extract data_counter? Below piece of code doesn't work for me.

```
value = ((address) & ((1 << 32) - 1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(1<<32)` won't do what you want because `1` is treated as a 32 bit int by default. So it tries to calculate `(1<<32)` as a 32 bit int. But a 32 bit int doesn't have enough bits to hold `(1<<32)`.

Use `(1L<<32)`. Then you will get a `long`, which is big enough to hold that number.

*Edit:*

For clarity, so you end up with:

```
value = (address & ((1L << 32) - 1));
```

Comment: And I don't need `-1`? I was following this formula `value=(fullvalue>>>shiftbitnumber)&((1<<bitsize)-1);`

Comment: No, you still need the minus one.

Comment: so it is just `1L` instead of `1` I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of suggestions.  Using the byte extraction method that you have proposed, it might be worth considering expressing shifts and masks in terms of `Byte.SIZE`, `Short.SIZE` and `Integer.SIZE` respectively.  Something like this:

```
public static long BYTE_MASK  = (1L << Byte.SIZE) - 1;
public static long SHORT_MASK = (1L << Short.SIZE) - 1;
public static long INT_MASK   = (1L << Integer.SIZE) - 1;

public static long DATACENTER_SHIFT = Integer.SIZE + Byte.SIZE + Short.SIZE;
// ...and so on
```

Alternatively, you could use a `ByteBuffer` to decode the value.  Something like this:

```
long value = 0x0200641600000078L; // example data from question
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.BYTES);
bb.putLong(value);
bb.flip();
byte  datacenter = bb.get();
short client_id = bb.getShort();
byte  data_id = bb.get();
int   data_counter = bb.getInt();
```

This might be worth considering if your incoming data is an array of bytes, perhaps from reading an `InputStream`, as you would be able to avoid assembling into a `long` and then disassembling into component pieces.  In this case, you could use `ByteBuffer.wrap(incomingByteArray)` instead of allocate/putLong/flip.